# Error retrieving data from firebase using addlistnerForSingleValueEvent

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my constructor class

```
public class selected_item {
    private String Items;
    public selected_item() {
    }

    public selected_item(String items) {
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public String getItems() {
        return Items;
    }
}
```

My mainActivity is given as

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
db.child("Category").child(s).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        selected_item Items =dataSnapshot.getValue(selected_item.class);
        System.out.println(Items);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

The output which I'm getting is

```
I/System.out: com.strease.user.strease.selected_item@3945e4f
```

Which is not required and also is not present anywhere on my database. The required output should be **Shoes**

Please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

You object doesn't have a `toString()` method, bacause of that Java gives you the reference for the object in the printing method.

Try printing the items attribute:

```
 System.out.println(Items.getItems());
```

You could also override the `toString()` method to print something readable:

```
public class selected_item {
    private String Items;
    public selected_item() {
    }

    public selected_item(String items) {
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public String getItems() {
        return Items;
    }

       @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Items;
        }

    }
```

And still user:

```
 System.out.println(Items);
```

Comment: or just override toString

Comment: glad I answered your question, don't forget to mark as answer so it can help others :)